# Is there any way to allow https to only selective application in Tomcat?

Tags: java, tomcat, https, tomcat8

I have a jax-ws based web application which is deployed to tomcat as a WAR file (XYZ.war), there are some other applications as well deployed.
I have configured https using self signed jks file and have configured connector in setting.xml file of tomcat. But it applies to all the web applications which are deployed.

Is there any way to only allow https to this particular application(XYZ) in Tomcat?

Comment: Is this a public site?  Is there a reason the other web apps can't use HTTPS?  There is a single listener so you can't really split them out.  But there are free SSL providers and your site may as well be completely protected.